# RTMP Stream Fast Forward / ReWind

Tags: streaming, red5, rtmp, jwplayer

I have recently setup a Red5 RTMP server which streams an MP4 (or FLV) to my instance of JWPlayer perfectly.

However, if you click on the seek bar (ie fast-forward or rewind) the player just hangs.  The 'buffer' icon appears in the middle of the player and just spins around until you refresh the page.

Any ideas?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though MP4 seeking is broken in Red5 at the moment (see http://code.google.com/p/red5/source/detail?r=4183 - it has already been fixed but it's not included in the current builds).

FLV seeking works just fine, with Red5 as well.